# update column dedicated to specific order

Tags: mysql

hello I have a table as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Master_Product`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Master_Product` (
  `KeyId_Product` bigint(21) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Id of table',
  `ID_OrderInform` bigint(21) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Order desire by user for ouput Inform Printed',
  `ID_OrderReport` bigint(21) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Order desire by user for ouput Report View Datatable',
  `Name_Product` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'PDF Name on disk',
  PRIMARY KEY (`KeyId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `KeyId` (`KeyId`),
  KEY `xID_OrderInform` (`ID_OrderInform`),
  KEY `xID_OrderReport` (`ID_OrderReport`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Each time i insert a new product i need fill this table with the order and name, but i cant use the `KeyId_Product` to sort in printed Inform or View Datatables, Becouse someone users need use a desirable order.

to get this scalability i need use 2 column aditional to store the desirable order, The problem occurs when a new product must be inserted between 2 existing products, and all products that with a higher index of ordering must be pushed `+1` to give space to the new one.

The only solution i find is use 2 query additional to update:

```
UPDATE 
    Master_Product
SET 
    ID_OrderInform = ID_OrderInform + 1 
WHERE 
    ID_OrderInform>$NewitemOrderInform
```

this other

```
UPDATE 
    Master_Product
SET 
    ID_OrderReport = ID_OrderReport + 1 
WHERE 
    ID_OrderReport>$NewitemOrderReport
```

how can I do all this in a single query, and if when updating the other products there is an error, apply the rolback that inpides even add the new record.

Comment: *I have a table as follows:* I very much doubt the veracity of this statement

Comment: maybe trigger will help you

Comment: How many rows are in the table? And how often do you insert new rows? Also `ID_OrderInform>$NewitemOrderInform` doesn't look correct - It should probably be `ID_OrderInform >= $NewitemOrderInform AND KeyId <> $NewItemKeyId`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel 5000 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does both "at the same time":

```
UPDATE  Master_Product
    SET ID_OrderInform = ID_OrderInform + (ID_OrderInform > $NewitemOrderInform),
        ID_OrderReport = ID_OrderReport + (ID_OrderReport > $NewitemOrderReport);
```

To explain,...  The `(id>$x)` is a boolean expression that evaluates to either `false` or `true`.  `false` is represented as `0`; `true` as `1`.  So this adds the 'correct' value (0 or 1) to each of the columns.

Meanwhile, a `PRIMARY KEY` *is a* `UNIQUE KEY`, so get rid of the redundant `UNIQUE KEY KeyId (KeyId)`.

What other queries hit this table?  It would probably be better to remove the indexes on `Inform` and `Report`.  It takes a significant amount of effort to update many of the rows in each for each master `UPDATE`.  And you probably only fetch all the rows when you need the ordered list.

A nitpick:  `BIGINT` is overkill.

Comment: yes i need make some changes in the Table structure.